# File name as parameter to main method

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, program-entry-point

In the test class for a main method, the parameter is set to a filename (this file contains integer data)

Here is the code snippet:

```
static Main main = new Main();
static
{
    String[] args = {"../data/filename.txt"};
    main.main(args);
}
```

Since the filename is passed as a parameter to the main method, the file name is of type String[].  This file needs to be parsed (or any other method possible) to get the information.  To do that, I used a scanner to look at it line by line.

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        List<Integer> left = new ArrayList(); 
        List<Integer> right = new ArrayList();

        try {
            Files.lines(Paths.get("filename.txt"))
                .map(l -> l.split("\\s")) 
                .forEachOrdered(l -> {
                    left.add(Integer.parseInt(l[0]));
                    right.add(Integer.parseInt(l[1]));
               });
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int[] leftArray = left.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
        int[] rightArray = right.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }
```

The issue here is that I've hard coded the file name into the Files.lines(Paths.get("filename.txt")), which I do not want.

Since the filename is passed as a parameter and it is of type String[] I cannot use args as the parameter for the file scanner.  My question is, how can I convert from String[] to String? OR is there an easier way to parse through the information? (keeping in mind that the filename will be the parameter for main)

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to index the `args` array? Just do this:

```
Files.lines(args[0])
```

On a side note, there's no point in instantiating `Main` in your test class. Just call the method statically:

```
static
{
    String[] args = {"../data/filename.txt"};
    Main.main(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just to take element out of String[] (array) ?

And arguments in java should go like that:

Args[0] - always program name
Args[1, 2 ..] - arguments

So i think you should change first code to :

```
static Main main = new Main();
static
{
    String[] args = {"Main","../data/filename.txt"};
    main.main(args);
}
```

and second code

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        List<Integer> left = new ArrayList(); 
        List<Integer> right = new ArrayList();

        try {
            Files.lines(Paths.get(args[1]))
                .map(l -> l.split("\\s")) 
                .forEachOrdered(l -> {
                    left.add(Integer.parseInt(l[0]));
                    right.add(Integer.parseInt(l[1]));
               });
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int[] leftArray = left.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
        int[] rightArray = right.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }
```

It's good change so it won't stop working when you take "real" arguments. Otherwise it'd take program name.